# A hereditarily Lindelöf $KC$-space $( X,τ )$ is Katětov-$KC$ if and only if there is a weaker sequential $US$ topology $σ⊂τ

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

> **A space $( X,τ )$  is said to be Katětov $ KC $ if there is a topology $ σ⊂τ$  such that
>   $( X,σ )$ is minimal $ KC $.**
>
> **The notion of strongly KC-spaces, that is, those spaces
>   in which every countably compact subset is closed.**
>
> **A topological space is called a $ US $-space provided that
>   each convergent sequence has a unique limit.**
>
> we can show that bellow statement is false.
>
> In a hereditarily Lindelöf $KC$-space $( X,τ )$ is Katětov-$KC$ if and
>   only if there is a weaker  $US$ topology و $σ⊂τ $.
>
> **But if we add sequential conditional it will be true, it means:**
>
> **Theorem**: "A hereditarily Lindelöf $KC$-space $( X,τ )$ is Katětov-$KC$ if and
>   only if there is a weaker sequential $US$ topology  $σ⊂τ $."
>
> **for proof I use these theorem, but I have not reached to exact result. can you help me?**
>
> (1):  A hereditarily Lindelöf KC-space $ ( X,τ )$ is Katětov-$KC$ if and
>   only if there is a weaker sequential KC topology $σ⊂τ $.
>
> (2): Let $ ( X,τ )$  be a strongly $KC$-space and $|X| < c $. Then $ ( X,τ )$  is
>   Katětov strongly $ KC $ if and only if there is a weaker sequential $US$ topology $σ⊂τ $ .

Answer (score 1):

This is Corollary $3.13$ of Weihua Sun, Yuming Xu, & Ning Li, ['On minimal strongly $KC$ spaces'](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/140482), *Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal*, Vol. $59$ ($2009$), No. $2$, $305$-$316$; the corollary is an obvious consequence of Theorem $3.12$, which is proved in full, and Lemma $3.10$, which says that a sequential $US$ space is strongly $KC$ (and hence $KC$).